# How to add new calculated variables to a data frame

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I would like to create a loop that will add now variables to the data frame.Those variables should be the simple quadratic form of the exsiting varibles.
In the example below I would like to have 3 new vars that are : `dat$birds_2 <- dat$birds^2`; `dat$wolfs_2 <- dat$wolfs^2`; `dat$snakes_2 <- dat$snakes^2`. I would like to do this for multiple variables at once.

```
dat <- read.table(text = " birds    wolfs     snakes
                    3        9         7
                    3        8         4
                    1        2         8
                    1        2         3
                    1        8         3
                    6        1         2
                    6        7         1
                    6        1         5
                    5        9         7
                    3        8         7
                    4        2         7
                    1        2         3
                    7        6         3
                    6        1         1
                    6        3         9
                    6        1         1   ",header = TRUE)
```

The needed output (`dat_new`) is (I show only the first 2 rows) :

```
 dat_new                      birds    wolfs     snakes birds_2    wolfs_2     snakes_2
                                3        9         7    9        81         49  
                                3        8         4    9        64         16
```

Comment: have you tried your code?... (because it is very likely to give you just what you want ;-)  except for the loop part of course)

Comment: I tried the apply function but I got only the values of the current variables.I'm new to looping so I don't know how should I begin.

Comment: just pass your code: `dat$birds_2<-dat$birds^2;   dat$wolfs_2<-dat$wolfs^2 ; dat$snakes_2<-dat$snakes^2`, you'll see 3 new variables in `dat` that are the square values of the corresponding variables. There is no need for a `loop` or `apply` function here, `^` is vectorized

Comment: A loop approach could be `dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) cbind(x, x^2))`

Comment: no experienced programmer would ever do it with a loop. Its slower and requires more lines of code. try to look for build in R functions that omit a loop.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding.. I meant that I would like to get a variables with quadratic value per each raw and not per column.

Comment: if what you want is not `dat$birds_2[1]==dat$birds[1]^2` and so on, you should add the desired output in your question

Comment: I edited the question by adding an output example.Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a one liner with `setNames`:

```
setNames(as.data.frame(cbind(dat, dat^2)), c(names(dat), paste0(names(dat),'_2')))

#   birds wolfs snakes birds_2 wolfs_2 snakes_2
#1      3     9      7       9      81       49
#2      3     8      4       9      64       16
```

Answer (score 9):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, paste0(names(dat),"_2") := lapply(.SD, '^', 2)]
head(dat,2)
#   birds wolfs snakes birds_2 wolfs_2 snakes_2
#1:     3     9      7       9      81       49
#2:     3     8      4       9      64       16
```

Or you can use `set` (which would be more efficient) as there are multiple columns

```
setDT(dat)
dat_new <- copy(dat)
for(j in 1:ncol(dat_new)){
   set(dat_new, i=NULL, j=j, value=dat_new[[j]]^2)
 }
 cbind(dat, dat_new)
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:20, 1e6*200, replace=TRUE), 
       ncol=200))

dat1 <- copy(dat)
dat2 <- copy(dat)


Colonel <- function() { setNames(as.data.frame(cbind(dat, dat^2)),
    c(names(dat), paste0(names(dat),'_2')))}
akrun1 <- function() {setDT(dat1)[, paste0(names(dat1),"_2") := 
            lapply(.SD, '^', 2)]}
akrun2 <- function() {setDT(dat2)
                  dat_new <- copy(dat2)
                  for(j in 1:ncol(dat_new)){
                      set(dat_new, i=NULL, j=j, value=dat_new[[j]]^2)
                   }
                  cbind(dat2, dat_new)}

jaap <- function() {dat_new <- dat %>% 
                     mutate_each(funs(.^2))
                names(dat_new) <- paste0(names(dat_new),"_2")
                dat_new <- cbind(dat,dat_new)}



 cathG <- function() {ncol_ori <- ncol(dat)
                datN <- cbind(dat, apply(dat, 2, "^", 2))
                colnames(datN)[(ncol_ori+1):ncol(datN)] <- 
            paste(colnames(datN)[1:ncol_ori], 2, sep="_")

     }

system.time(Colonel())
#   user  system elapsed 
#  5.589   1.472  46.843 

 system.time(akrun1())
 #   user  system elapsed 
 #  2.125   1.238  10.065 

system.time(akrun2())
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.522   0.744   3.922 

system.time(jaap())
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.597   0.926  11.153 

system.time(cathG())
#   user  system elapsed 
#  9.386   3.536  94.360
```

Comment: interesting you really like to benchmark! Surely the `as.data.frame` conversion taking time. I modified it to `data.frame`.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I think `as.data.frame` is faster

Answer (score 7):

You can do the following (not using a loop):

```
dat_2 <- dat^2
colnames(dat_2) <- paste0(colnames(dat),"_2")
dat_tot <- cbind(dat, dat_2)
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding.. I meant that I would like to get a variables with quadratic value per each raw and not per column.

Comment: try `rbind()` instead of `cbind()` then. I am however not sure if I understand the edited question anymore.

Comment: the code above does the exact thing as your output example

Comment: You are right, but how can change the new vars names?

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative, you can also do this quite easily with the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

dat_new <- dat %>% mutate_all(funs(.^2))
names(dat_new) <- paste0(names(dat_new),"_2")
dat_new <- cbind(dat,dat_new)
```

this gives:

```
> head(dat_new)
  birds wolfs snakes birds_2 wolfs_2 snakes_2
1     3     9      7       9      81       49
2     3     8      4       9      64       16
3     1     2      8       1       4       64
4     1     2      3       1       4        9
5     1     8      3       1      64        9
6     6     1      2      36       1        4
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get quadratic values for some variables *(**eg** variables 1 to 10 of `dat`)*, you can do:

```
ncol_ori <- ncol(dat)
dat <- cbind(dat, apply(dat[, 1:10], 2, "^", 2)) # or actually just cbind(dat, dat[, 1:10]^2)
colnames(dat)[(ncol_ori+1):ncol(dat)] <- paste(colnames(dat)[1:10], 2, sep="_")
```

***If you want to do that for all the variables of your original data.frame, you can do:***

```
ncol_ori <- ncol(dat)
dat <- cbind(dat, apply(dat, 2, "^", 2)) # or just cbind(dat, dat^2)
colnames(dat)[(ncol_ori+1):ncol(dat)] <- paste(colnames(dat)[1:ncol_ori], 2, sep="_")
```

with your `dat`, you'll get:

```
head(dat)
#   birds wolfs snakes birds_2 wolfs_2 snakes_2
#1      3     9      7       9      81       49
#2      3     8      4       9      64       16
#3      1     2      8       1       4       64
#4      1     2      3       1       4        9
#5      1     8      3       1      64        9
#6      6     1      2      36       1        4
```

Comment: That is great, but how can I change the new variables name for example adding "_2" in the end of the name?

Comment: @mql4beginner, I added 2 lines so you can name your columns with new variables with "_2" in the end

Comment: Hello @CathG, I fet an error with  dat <- cbind(dat, apply(dat[, 1:10], 2, "^", 2)).the error is:"Error in `[.data.frame`(dat, , 1:10) : undefined columns selected"

Comment: @mql4beginner, maybe because you have less than 10 columns in `dat` ? if so, replace `1:10` by the indices of the column for which you want the quadratic value. If you want it for all columns, you can go with the second piece of code in my answer

Comment: Yes I changed to the right number of columns and now It is working..Thanks